# ajax spinner start stop don`t work

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, spinner

I want to start and stop in ajax process below mentioned spinner css, but could not. Please advice.
  "CSS" code doesn't run when ajax start and stop in jsp file.

**CSS code :**

```
.cssload-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}

.cssload-zenith {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px rgb(255,255,255);
    animation: cssload-spin 510ms infinite linear;
    -o-animation: cssload-spin 510ms infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: cssload-spin 510ms infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: cssload-spin 510ms infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: cssload-spin 510ms infinite linear;
}



@keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -o-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

**html code:**

```
<div class="cssload-container">
    <div class="cssload-zenith"></div>
</div>
```

**jquery code:**

```
$('.cssload-container').ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show();
});
$('.cssload-container').ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to correct your functions:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
   $('.cssload-container').show();
}

$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
   $('.cssload-container').hide();
}
```

**Original Example:**

In your ajax call the `startSpinner` / `stopSpinner` functions below

```js
function startSpinner() {
  $('.cssload-container').show();
}

function stopSpinner() {
  $('.cssload-container').hide();
}
```

```css
.cssload-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}

.cssload-zenith {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px rgb(255,255,255);
    animation: cssload-spin 510ms infinite linear;
    -o-animation: cssload-spin 510ms infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: cssload-spin 510ms infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: cssload-spin 510ms infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: cssload-spin 510ms infinite linear;
}



@keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -o-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="startSpinner()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stopSpinner()">Stop</button>

<div class="cssload-container">
    <div class="cssload-zenith">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: pls, run code before share.  what is spinner? i want run spinner on ajax  in your code  its run nonestop

Comment: I did run the code. You call one function - startSpinner() when you first make the ajax call, and then other - stopSpinner() when the ajax call returns the data. That starts and stops the spinner during the ajax request

Comment: I see what you're saying. I've updated my answer to make it clearer

Comment: Also, make sure you have content, some text or an image, in the `cssload-zenith` div when testing, otherwise it will appear like it isn't working.

Comment: Without any code, and provided you haven't included a `display: none;`, put some text in the spinner as I've done and it should show.  That's the first thing to check

Comment: in your solution i must call start and stop in every ajax click. i have 50 ajax clicks. it will be hard me to do id. i write easy solution in my question - i want to too see sppiner when ajax start and stop - with 4 rows code which i wrote. my code works when i put img src spinner  insead of css code . but  interesting why it dont work with css. ?

Comment: You don't need to do it 50 times or whatever. You can call my functions once in your AjaxStart / ajaxStop functions. I just couldn't provide a simple demo including Ajax. The Css will not show anything unless you have some content in the div. Without content the height and width is zero. That's why I added the "Text". Anyway, did you see my edit? I provided the syntax using your functions.

Comment: i did as you wirte , but no result. for check jquery code  i wrote alert  after 
 start and stop function  - when jquery start and stop it worked. but when i wrote this code, no result : $('.cssload-container').ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show();
});
$('.cssload-container').ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show().hide();
})

Comment: i did also  display: block in css file- spinner works when page run. but i try to hide via jquery it dont worked

Comment: You haven't used what I wrote. The code you are showing me is your code, not mine. Your code is not going to work, and I can tell that just by looking at it

Comment: There are two problems with your code: 1) using `$(this)` - here `this` does not refer to your `div`, it refers to something completely different, so you can't use `this` here. 2) if you're using jQuery >= 1.9 then .ajaxStart() method, must be attached to `document` and not an element. Ie. `$(document).ajaxStart(function() {...})`, and not `$('.cssload-container').ajaxStart(...` as you have done (http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/).

Comment: So again, I refer you to the top of my answer where I have corrected these problems.